# How to get timestamp based on wordpress setting

Tags: wordpress, datetime, plugins

I am coding a simple wordpress plugin and uses the `time()` function but I notice that it returns the server unix timestamp, not in the timezone that I set inside wordpress.

How can I retrieve the unix timestamp based on the wordpress timezone setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `current_time`.

```
<?php
    echo "Your local site time: " . date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
?>
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [current_time](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/)

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of the main time functions accept parameters. I think it would be smart to change that.

```
wp_date( string $format, int $timestamp = null, DateTimeZone $timezone
= null ) Retrieves the date, in localized format.

Parameters #Parameters $format (string) (Required) PHP date format.

$timestamp (int) (Optional) Unix timestamp. Defaults to current time.

Default value: null

$timezone (DateTimeZone) (Optional) Timezone to output result in. Defaults to timezone from site settings.

Default value: null
```